# java-8 filter a list without creating a new list

Tags: java, list, lambda, java-8

I'm looking for the cleanest way to filter a list in Java-8, with a simple lambda `Predicate`, **without creating a new list**.

In particular, this solution is not suitable, as `toList()` returns a new `List`:

```
List<Person> beerDrinkers = persons.stream()
    .filter(p -> p.getAge() > 16)
    .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Note that the following solution does not work either, because the list should be `clear()`ed of its original values (but obviously, if you clear it *before* filtering, there's nothing left to filter...):

```
persons.stream()
    .filter(p -> p.getAge() > 16)
    .forEach((p) -> persons.add(p));
```

(Also, I'd prefer a solution not involving the use of a 3rd party library or framework)

Comment: Check out https://github.com/wapatesh/fig , you may need it in many cases

Answer (score 38, accepted):

```
beerDrinkers.removeIf(p -> p.getAge() <= 16);
```

Comment: A side note: This may have a quadratic asymptotic running time (depending on the type of the list), whereas filtering and collecting will always be O(n)

Comment: @Marco13 It won't with ArrayList nor with LinkedList, which are by far the most commonly used lists, though. Do you have a specific List implementation in mind?

Comment: @JBNizet Apologies, I thought this would have O(n²) for an `ArrayList`, due to the O(n) for `remove(E)` on ArrayList, but in fact, there is a dedicated implementation for the `removeIf`  in `ArrayList` that uses a `BitSet` to first find out the elements to be removed, and then compacts the elements of the `ArrayList` in one run. Now I consider deleting the above comment (and this one), although it would still be true for any list where `remove(E)` is an O(n) operation and that uses the *default* implementation of `removeIf` that is defined in the `Collection` interface...

Comment: No need to apologize. Don't delete the comment. It's useful to ask yourself such a question when dealing with a default method, and it might clear the doubts of future readers. I myself had to check the documentation (and the code) to ensure that ArrayList overrode the method.

Comment: @Marco13 I agree with JB Nizet; this is a useful discussion. It may also be worth noting that the conventional approach of using an `Iterator` and deleting matching elements one at a time may have O(n^2) performance, at least with an `ArrayList`.

Comment: wow, this comment section is the best, got to know about so many things, thanks for not deleting these comments