# Will Java 8 create a new List after using Stream "filter" and "collect"?

Tags: java, list, java-8, java-stream

I have code using Java8:

```
List<Integer> list = new ArrayList<Integer>();
list.add(3);
list.add(5);
list.add(4);
list.add(2);
list.add(5);
list = list.stream().filter(i -> i >= 3).collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Original list is [3, 5, 4, 2, 5]. After "filter" and "collect" operation, the list changes to [3, 5, 4, 5].

Are all the operations perform on original list and does not create a new list? Or after "filter" and "collect" operation, return a new created list and ignore original list?

Comment: Which operation do you think is performed on the original list? The `filter`'s `Predicate` operates on a value from the list if that's what you mean. `Stream` returns a `Stream` that has a reference to the `list` if that's what you mean.

Comment: @steffen, I think mainly because author didn't even read the documentation for `collect` method before asking.

Comment: @steffen This question is unclear and does not show any research effort. It is unclear because it doesn't specify what makes them think the original list would be modified or what they mean by _perform_. It doesn't show any research effort because the javadoc for `Collectors.toList()` is very clear that it returns a new list. Additionally, with their example, it's trivial to verify whether or not the original was modified.

Comment: @steffen I find it... https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Collectors.html#toList--

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis I find it: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Collectors.html#toList--

Comment: That's great. Please try to find it before asking a question or reference it in your question and explain what part of it confuses you and why.

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis Originally I'm looking into `Stream` doc, and find no useful info, now I find the right doc:) Thanks all!

Comment: @user3707125 My careless not to find the right doc... Find the doc https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Collectors.html#toList--

Comment: You don't need to study the `Collector`'s documentation. There is a simpler, fundamental principle to keep in mind: the source doesn't need to be a list and a stream doesn't provide any way to find out, whether the source is a list, not to speak about access to that list. Thus, it's impossible for a `Collector` to deal with the original list in any way.

Comment: If you want to do it in-place, modifying the original list: `list.removeIf(i -> i<3);`

Comment: Mh. Someone censored my comment :-(

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31760421/java-8-filter-a-list-without-creating-a-new-list

Answer (score 37, accepted):

According to the [Javadoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Collectors.html#toList--), passing the `Collector` returned by `Collectors.toList()` into the `collect` method will create a new list.

> `public static <T> Collector<T,?,List<T>> toList()`
>
> Returns a `Collector` that accumulates the input elements into a new `List`. There are no guarantees on the type, mutability, serializability, or thread-safety of the `List` returned; if more control over the returned `List` is required, use `toCollection(Supplier)`.

The original list remains unaffected.

Comment: Thanks! Also attach doc: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Collectors.html#toList--

Answer (score 29):

If you actually want to modify the original list, consider using [`removeIf`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Collection.html#removeIf-java.util.function.Predicate-):

```
list.removeIf(i -> i < 2);
```

Answer (score 5):

Stream operations are either intermediate or terminal. 
**Intermediate operations** return a stream so you can chain multiple intermediate operations.
**Terminal** operations return void or something else.

Most of stream operations are non-interfering, it means that they don't modify the data source of the stream.
But by calling the `collect` method you are creating a new list and you're assigning it to `list`

Comment: Cool! That means `list.stream().filter(i -> i >= 3);` does not change original list.

Comment: All stream operations are non-interfering (none of them modify the data source), as long as the parameters that you give to them are non-interfering too.

Comment: Chris does filter (or any intermediate operation) creates a new Stream()?

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
List<Integer> list = new ArrayList<Integer>();
list.add(3);
list.add(5);
list.add(4);
list.add(2);
list.add(5);
List<Integer> list2 = list.stream().filter(i -> i >= 3).collect(Collectors.toList());
System.out.println("list:  "+list);
System.out.println("list2: "+list2);
```

Answer (score 1):

Referring to Guava Lists.transform() function will help you understand why a new list needs to generate. Before JDK 7, Lists.transform() function is strongly recommended to implement similar feature.